# User control validation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have 3 User controls which have sets of questions and answers. Each usercontrol has a next button. The third user control has a submit button.

On clicking the submit button I need to trigger a required field validator in all 3 usercontrols. How can i achieve this?

Comment: The next button makes the user control to get invisible on the client side via javascript or does it become invisible via a regular postback and there the Visible property gets set in code behind?

Comment: You can get a reference to the button using ClientID property and attach a java script to each button on page load by adding an attribute i.e.: btnFirstQuestion.Attributes.Add("onclick","<your method code>");. 

It would be helpful if you described what exactly you have problems with ;).

Comment: In my case the next button clears the previous control from the placeholder and loads the new controls and adds it to the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `style="display:none"` to hide the panels, then if you tie all the validators to the same validationgroup as the button, they will all fire.  If you use server-side Visible="false", then this may still be the case, but only with server-side validation since hidden content doesn't render.

Comment: The next button clears the previous control from the placeholder and loads the new controls and adds it to the placeholder. Is this the correct way? Can you give me an example.?

Comment: Oh, so you are dynamically validating input... here is where the challenge lies.  You can't use the ASP.NET validation system to do this; instead, you have to programmably check each value from the server, and render out the errors by hand.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can share some example.